# How to avoid multiple sourcemaps for lazy loaded modules?

Tags: javascript, webpack, source-maps

We have multiple bundles generated by webpack. Each bundle has few common modules like (A.js and B.js which is present in Bundles B1,B2 and B3).

While debugging in chrome we face this issue where multiple source maps get referenced and we don't know which sourcemap to use. These are present only in three bundles and I don't want to move them to a common module. Is there anything which could be done to avoid this scenario.

[image: Multiple source maps]

Thanks in advance